# Shorthand syntax for PHP arrays

Tags: php, syntax

Is this valid PHP syntax or just a shorthand for the documentation? **Does anybody have the link to a help page describing this notation?**

```
$array = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];
```

If you have a look at the code examples in the [Unpacking nested arrays with list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach.list) section on the `foreach` help page you will see this possibly new notation, however I can't seem to find any help for this.

Comment: If you'd try running the code you would quickly find out if it works or not.

Comment: @Jessica I haven't got 5.5 installed - have you???

Comment: its just short hand for an array of arrays i believe

Comment: It's correct as of 5.4+ , the shorthand `[]` mirrors the same functionality as `array()`

Comment: _"I haven't got 5.5 installed"_ - http://3v4l.org/VNp6s

Comment: It works on 5.4. I don't see anything in the link you posted for 5.5 about the array syntax.

Comment: @Jessica Maybe if you actually read my whole post instead of just down voting me you would see exactly where it is!

Comment: It was a lazy question, why do you expect non-lazy answers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new syntax `[]` was added in [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php). Check out the documentation on [arrays](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: "As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []."

Answer (score 4):

The page you reference is saying that unpacking the array using `list()` is new in PHP 5.5, not the short array syntax itself, which was added in PHP 5.4.

> PHP 5.5 added the ability to iterate over an array of arrays and
>   unpack the nested array into loop variables by providing a list() as
>   the value.

Answer (score 2):

That is no more than an array of arrays. These two snippets are identical:

```
$array = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];

$array = array(
  array (1, 2),
  array (3, 4),
);
```

This is documented in [the PHP manual page for Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func) and has been possible since PHP 5.4.

Comment: I know what it means. I am asking if it is valid PHP now & do you have a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just test the code?
I'm using PHP Version 5.4.7 and it is already valid code.
Example:

```
$array = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```